# What comes first: the hook or the rest?

Tags: lyrics

What is generally accepted method or writing a good song? To start with the hook and let the rest of the song point to it, or start from the beginning and let the hook come naturally? Is there a "best-practice" stated somewhere?

Comment: This is my first post. Please be kind :) Also I wanted to add the tags [songwriting] and [hooks] but can't yet with my low rep. That'd be great if someone added those.

Comment: No way are you 53. You look like my cousin.

Comment: @KitFox Those are my initials.

Comment: I've added "songwriting," as that may be a useful tag, but I think "hooks" is too specific. And good question!

Comment: The tag has since disappeared, @Lauren. I don't know if you still think it's a good idea, but if you want it to stick to a single question you should add a tag wiki.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can point you to a very good resource on hooks in songs, whether you are talking about lyric or musical hooks.  The resource is the great (albeit older) book, [The Craft of Lyric Writing, by Sheila Davis](http://amzn.to/2qzxaJt).

The book is filled withe examples from real hits and other songs which have been produced by actual recording companies.

The author touches upon the entire process of song writing and how the hook impacts the song and how the song impacts the hook.  Also, explains the importance of a hook is actually based in the audience's memory.  In other words, you create the hooks to help the audience (whether listener or producer) remember your song.
Good luck.